# task declaration not working in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have gradle file with below code which is failing.

```
task wakeup
task dressup
task playMusic
task goRunning

//dependsOn(task)

wakeup <<{  
    println("I am awake,i need to go for a run")
}

dressup(dependsOn: wakeup)<<{
    println("I am ready with my track suit")
}

playMusic(dependsOn: dressup)<<{
    println("I have played track 7")
}

goRunning(dependsOn: playMusic)<<{
    println("I am running")
}
```

**ERROR:-**

```
C:\Users\akathaku\Desktop\gradlelearning>gradle -q -b taskmethods.gradle goRunning

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\akathaku\Desktop\gradlelearning\taskmethods.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradlelearning'.
> Could not find method dressup() for arguments [{dependsOn=task ':wakeup'}] on root project 'gradlelearning'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

But if i change the code to:-

```
//dependsOn(task)

task wakeup <<{ 
    println("I am awake,i need to go for a run")
}

task dressup(dependsOn: wakeup)<<{
    println("I am ready with my track suit")
}

task playMusic(dependsOn: dressup)<<{
    println("I have played track 7")
}

task goRunning(dependsOn: playMusic)<<{
    println("I am running")
}
```

Its running perfectly. Normaly declaring a task and using it later works.But with dependsOn method this is failing.Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't the `dependsOn method`, as clearly it works in your second example.

The problem is that you're missing the `task` declaration when trying to define the task body, so gradle interprets the groovy code as a method call. Meaning, when you write:

```
dressup(dependsOn: wakeup)<<{
    println("I am ready with my track suit")
}
```

Gradle doesn't recognize it as a task, but rather sees the `dressup(dependsOn: wakeup)` portion as you trying to call a method named `dressup` with the parameter `{dependsOn: wakeup}`. But no such method exists, and you get the error.

Which is why you always need to tell gradle that it's a task, i.e.:

```
task dressup(dependsOn: wakeup)<<{
    println("I am ready with my track suit")
}
```

As per your second (and successful) example.